# Nuxt.js nested route loading issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

ALL the above code comes from my file _id.vue in the pages/apibuilder/models folder

I use this to populate my store with datas

```
async asyncData({ store }) {
    // this.datas = await this.$axios
    //  .$get('/api/apibuilder/retrievemodel')
    //  .then(function (res) {
    //      return res
    //  })
    return { datas: await store.dispatch('apibuilder/retrieve_model') }
},
```

I use these datas in 2 different ways in the template

1 in a v-for loop

```
<tr v-for="(data, name, index) in $store.state.apibuilder.currentModel.attributes":key="index">
```

2 I want to display the number of this $store.state.apibuilder.currentModel.attributes
I do it like this

```
<span> {{Object.keys($store.state.apibuilder.currentModel.attributes).length}}Champs</span>
```

if I navigate with nuxtlink to my nested page : http://localhost:3000/apibuilder/models/Article everything works perfectly, I got my loop and my count working

but if I try to refresh the page or acces the site directly from the url

I get the loop working, but not the count
I have an error telling me that $store.state.apibuilder.currentModel.attributes is null and it breaks the object.keys().length

the code 1 and 2 are really close to each other within the template and yet, it is Null one time and it display the loop few line after.

Any idea?

Ps,

i tryed to do the count stuff in a computed property but it's the same, the datas are undefined when i reload the page.

i also tryed with SSR = true and SSR = false

i also tryed with fetch instead of asyncData

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the problem is linked to fetch or asyncData.

You fetch the data and store it in the state. That's good. But after that, you should not use the `store.state` : use instead a getters (I find it cleaner to use `mapGetters`).

Your store will be liked that :

```
export const state = () => ({
    apibuilder: {},
});
export const getters = {
    attributes(state) {
        return state.apibuilder.currentModel.attributes;
    }
}
```

And in your component :

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            attributes: 'attributes',
        }),
        countAttributes() {
            if (this.attributes) {
               return Object.keys(this.attributes).length
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to that, it will react to the change of data in the store.